# Get only some properties from an entity using Repository pattern and LINQ2Entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I know it's pretty standard stuff but right know the solution escapes me.  I have entity `Documents`. In my service I can call `DocumentsRepository.All()` and then use only what I need but I don't want to carry all the unneeded data. I guess I have to use anonymous object to achieve this, but the exact implementation escapes me.

In `Documents` entity I have column `Id` and column `UserId`. How can I write my LINQ to only get those two values?

P.S

And what type should I use for my method? Maybe `object` but I would like something more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you need, if you want to put this into a method you should create a type that contains all the info you need.

```
var selectedItems = context.Documents.Select(d => new
    {
        Id = d.Id,
        UserId = d.UserId
    });
```

**EDIT**

Use in a method:

```
public class MyData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<MyData> GetMyDataFromDocuments()
{
    return context.Documents.Select(d => new MyData
        {
            Id = d.Id,
            UserId = d.UserId
        });
}
```

Comment: Thnaks, like this the method should return `object` right? Do you think there's solution where it can return something more specific?

Comment: @Leron make a class and change `d => new` to `d => new MyClass`.

Comment: @Leron  I have just added more info, will post a full example.

Comment: @Oliver Ty, I have thought for additional class too but thought would be an overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: @Leron I personally do not think this is overkill if the method is used multiple times throughout your application.  I would not use a dynamic return type to perform this task.  If this method was single use, I would consider placing the transformation only where it was required, and not having an intermediary class.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon olivers answer, if you want to return that from a method, you could use dynamic:

```
    public dynamic ReturnSomeData()
    {
        return context.Documents.Select(d => new
        {
            Id = d.Id,
            UserId = d.UserId
        });
    }
```

You have to keep in mind that you trade compiler checking for flexibility.